# How to create a generic return type for OAuth Authentication using Go

Tags: go, oauth

I want to abstract the logic for oauth authentication and I've built the following code:

```
provider, _ := utils.ChooseProviderFromString(data.Provider)
user, _ := provider.TryLogin(OAuthAccessToken)
```

The provider comes as a string from the client (e.g facebook, github, google, whatever). Then we pass it to the `ChooseProviderFromString` method and returns the corresponding struct, and then we try to login.

So good so far as an idea, but yet I am stuck.

```
type OAuthAuthenticator interface {
    TryLogin(accessToken string) (WHAT_TYPE_DO_I_NEED_HERE, error)
}
type FacebookAuthenticator struct {
    accessToken string
}
func (fbAuth *FacebookAuthenticator) TryLogin(accessToken string) (*FacebookUserResponse, error) {
    return GetFacebookUser(accessToken)
}

func ChooseProviderFromString(provider string) (OAuthAuthenticator, error)  {
    if provider == "facebook" {
        return &FacebookAuthenticator{}, nil
    }

    return nil, errors.New("invalid provider")
}
```

You see that we choose the correct provider and return a new struct from it, similar to a factory. The problem is that I can't finish my idea, since I've got no clue what type I should write for the login response: `TryLogin(accessToken string) (WHAT_TYPE_DO_I_NEED_HERE, error)`

If we pass `facebook` as a string, we will return a new `FacebookAuthenticator`. When we call `TryLogin` it has to detect the authenticator and return the correct UserResponse (FacebookUserResponse, GithubUserResponse etc)

How can I fix this?

Comment: In my opinion this depends entirely upon how you wanna use the result from `TryLogin`, say, if you're just gonna pass the result off to a json marshaler, then the proper type to return would be `interface{}`. If, however, you need to read a few details from the returned value then you could do with a non-empty interface, or a "common" user struct type to which the authenticators would convert their specific result... Try updating your question with details on how you need to use the `TryLogin` result, what the "consumer" of the authenticator code needs to do with the result.

Comment: Creating an empty interface solved my issue, thank you!